# Arcgisbinding: comand arc.data2 does not find the loaded package sp

Tags: r, gis, arcgis, r-sp

I´m using R in ArcGIS to write scripttools. It was working properly for some time but since today I get the Error: "Error in arc.data2sp : This function requires the sp package".

I reinstalled arcgisbinding and sp.

sp und arcgisbinding have the newest versions.
sp Version: 1.6-0
arcgisbinding version 1.0.1.300

Sp is installed and it is loaded at the beginning of the script.

arcgisbinding works on the newest version of R.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for people to be able to help you, you should provide a code example. Copy the code required to reproduce your error and paste it to your answer. Use ``` at the beginning and the end of the code sequence to format it properly.